# Is it true that every isomorphism of hypersurface can be lifted to ambient projective space?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to X'$ be isomorphism between hypersurfaces of dimension $n-1$ ( in $\mathbb P^n$). Is it true that we can always lift this $f$ to $\mathbb P^n$?

I have already seen that for very general case this is true. My approach is using the very ample line bundle $\mathcal O_X(1)=i^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$ ($i$ is the embedding in $\mathbb P^n$). If $f^*\mathcal O_{X'}(1)=\mathcal O_{X}(1)$ and $h^0(X,\mathcal O_{X}(1))=n+1$ then obviously we can lift $f$ to $\mathbb P^n$.

So we need two conditions:

1. $h^0(X,\mathcal O_{X}(1))=n+1$. Using the exact sequence $0\to \mathcal O(1-d)\to \mathcal O(1) \to \mathcal O_X(1)\to 0$ this is true if $h^0(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O(1-d))=h^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O(1-d))=0$ , which trivially holds for $d>1$. So this is okay.
2. $f^*\mathcal O_{X'}(1)=\mathcal O_{X}(1)$. I don't know if this is always true? I know for $n>3$ the Picard group of hypersurface is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. And the canonical bundle of $X$ is $\mathcal O_X(d-n-1)$. So if $d-n-1\neq 0$ we always have $f^*\mathcal O_{X'}(1)=\mathcal O_{X}(1)$. But I feel very uncomfortable with the condition $d-n-1\neq 0$. Is there any way to avoid it?

Or, if there is another way to show this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tis is in general false, for example, smooth cubic plane curves.

Comment: @Mohan Then, is it always true for $n>3$?

Comment: If $n>3$, then any smooth hypersurface has Picard group generated by $\mathcal{O}(1)$, so you are done as you said. $n=2$, my example says it can fail. I do not know the result fot $n=3$.

Comment: For $n=3$ it is true when the degree is at least $5$, or when the degree is $3$ (cubic surfaces). (I assume you are only interested in smooth hypersurfaces.) For smooth quartic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (K3 surfaces) the linear automorphism group is finite. (This is the group of automorphisms you are interested in.) However, there are smooth quartic surfaces with infinitely many automorphisms (which do not come from the ambient space). Thus, the answer is negative for smooth cubic curves and smooth quartic surfaces. But those are the only exceptions.